# What is Java 21s new Sequence Interface

Tags: java, collections, interface, java-21

What is the new `Sequence` interface in [Java 21](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_21)? What does it add and what may be common issues to consider?

Comment: Have you considered consulting the documentation?

Comment: @user207421 The OP is obviously not actually asking this question and is instead trying to provide a "canonical reference" for questions about `SequencedCollection` and `SequencedMap`. Now, whether you think this a worthwhile Q&A is a different issue.

Comment: It is encouraged to document new things and answer your own question. See https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: There is no new interface in Java 21 called `Sequence`.

Answer (score 3):

There is no new interface in Java 21 called `Sequence`.  Rather, there are three related interfaces: [`SequencedCollection`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/SequencedCollection.html), [`SequencedSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/SequencedSet.html), and [`SequencedMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/SequencedMap.html).  These three interfaces represent collections or maps which have a well-defined iteration order, as well as the ability to be viewed in reverse.

These three types were added by the [JEP 431: Sequenced Collections](https://openjdk.org/jeps/431) feature.  Per its summary, its goal was to:

> Introduce new interfaces to represent collections with a defined encounter order. Each such collection has a well-defined first element, second element, and so forth, up to the last element. It also provides uniform APIs for accessing its first and last elements, and for processing its elements in reverse order.

These new interface types can be used any time a `Collection`, `Set`, or `Map` is needed in which the iteration order is important.

These new interfaces were added to the existing collection hierarchy where appropriate.  `List`, `Deque`, and `SequencedSet` extend `SequencedCollection` directly.  `SortedSet` and `LinkedHashSet` extend `SequencedSet`.  And `SortedMap` and `LinkedHashMap` both extend `SequencedMap`.

The mutation methods in the interfaces (`addFirst`, `putLast`, etc) are all *optional* methods, which are only implemented by types where that sort of mutation makes sense.  For instance, `addFirst` is not implemented for `SortedSet`, since the encounter order is defined by the comparison function between the elements, so an arbitrary element cannot be added to the beginning of the set.

## Interface methods

### `SequencedCollection`

`SequencedCollection` extends `Collection` and provides methods to add, retrieve, and remove the first and last element.  It also provides a method to provide a reversed view of the collection.  Per the Javadoc method summary:

| Modifier and Type | Method | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `default void` | `addFirst(E e)` | Adds an element as the first element of this collection (optional operation). |
| `default void` | `addLast(E e)` | Adds an element as the last element of this collection (optional operation). |
| `default E` | `getFirst()` | Gets the first element of this collection. |
| `default E` | `getLast()` | Gets the last element of this collection. |
| `default E` | `removeFirst()` | Removes and returns the first element of this collection (optional operation). |
| `default E` | `removeLast()` | Removes and returns the last element of this collection (optional operation). |
| `SequencedCollection<E>` | `reversed()` | Returns a reverse-ordered view of this collection. |

### `SequencedSet`

`SequencedSet` extends both `SequencedCollection` and `Set`.  It is identical to `SequencedCollection`, except that its `reversed` view returns a `SequencedSet` rather than a `SequencedCollection`.

| Modifier and Type | Method | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `SequencedSet<E>` | `reversed()` | Returns a reverse-ordered view of this collection. |

### `SequencedMap`

`SequencedMap` extends `Map` and provides methods to retrieve, put, and poll elements from the map.  It also provides a method to provide a reversed view of the map.  Per the Javadoc method summary:

| Modifier and Type | Method | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `default Map.Entry<K,V>` | `firstEntry()` | Returns the first key-value mapping in this map, or null if the map is empty. |
| `default Map.Entry<K,V>` | `lastEntry()` | Returns the last key-value mapping in this map, or null if the map is empty. |
| `default Map.Entry<K,V>` | `pollFirstEntry()` | Removes and returns the first key-value mapping in this map, or null if the map is empty (optional operation). |
| `default Map.Entry<K,V>` | `pollLastEntry()` | Removes and returns the last key-value mapping in this map, or null if the map is empty (optional operation). |
| `default V` | `putFirst(K k, V v)` | Inserts the given mapping into the map if it is not already present, or replaces the value of a mapping if it is already present (optional operation). |
| `default V` | `putLast(K k, V v)` | Inserts the given mapping into the map if it is not already present, or replaces the value of a mapping if it is already present (optional operation). |
| `SequencedMap<K,V>` | `reversed()` | Returns a reverse-ordered view of this map. |
| `default SequencedSet<Map.Entry<K,V>>` | `sequencedEntrySet()` | Returns a SequencedSet view of this map's entrySet. |
| `default SequencedSet<K>` | `sequencedKeySet()` | Returns a SequencedSet view of this map's keySet. |
| `default SequencedCollection<V>` | `sequencedValues()` | Returns a SequencedCollection view of this map's values collection. |

Answer (score 2):

The `Sequence` interface is Java’s standardization of sequential `Collections` that have a logical ordering, or as [*JEP 431: Sequenced Collections*](https://openjdk.org/jeps/431) puts it, “a defined encounter order”. A `SortedSet` would be able to keep its natural ordering, a `List` keeps its insertion order etc.

The methods that it adds are

```
SequencedCollection<E> reversed();
void addFirst(E);
void addLast(E);
E getFirst();
E getLast();
E removeFirst();
E removeLast();
```

The `getFirst()` method can replace `list.get(0)`, `deque.getFirst()`, `sortedSet.first()`, and `linkedHashSet.iterator().next()`. The same for `getLast()` except `LinkedHashSet` had no get last and you would have to iterate the entire Set.

There is some strangeness IMO to this regarding `SortedSet`. `SortedSet` is forced to implement the `addFirst()` and `addLast()` methods which don’t make sense in context and the Jep says “these methods can throw `UnsupportedOperationException`”.

`Reversed()` also standardizes how to iterate backwards. Previously, there was `navSet.descendingSet()`, `deque.descendingIterator()`, and `for (var it = list.listIterator(list.size()); it.hasPrevious();) {}` and again `LinkedHashSet` has no method. Now `reversed()` allows all the standard iteration techniques of fors, streams etc. and includes `LinkedHashSet`.
One final note is that if a codebase used these method names they will run into issues. See the [Jep](https://openjdk.org/jeps/431) for a full description of the item.[image: Inheritence of Sequence]

Comment: there is no "`Sequence` interface" in Java 21 (or 22) - Only a [`Sequence` class](https://download.java.net/java/early_access/jdk22/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/sound/midi/Sequence.html), and that is related to MIDI (sound) - better use correct nomenclature... (if just *mimicking* the documentations)

Comment: The correct name is [`SequencedCollection`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/SequencedCollection.html), as shown in the diagram.

Comment: @Holger Or `SequencedMap` if dealing with a `Map`.